# When should an answer be deleted?

Tags: discussion, policy, deleting

I was checking the answers that have been deleted, and I noticed that [Do journals in general have any kind of policy regarding papers submitted by someone without a research affiliation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/385/do-scientific-journals-in-general-have-any-kind-of-policy-regarding-papers-submi/388#388) has been deleted by Anna Lear. Not that I complain particularly about deleting this answer, but I'm not sure to see the reason why. I mean, the answer should probably have been given as a comment to [my answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/386/102), since it was a comment on something I wrote, but apart from this, it was correctly written, and it wasn't a spam. Was it flagged by someone?

Sorry to ask, but I'm a bit of a newbie on Stack Exchange, so I'd just like to understand the policy, and what we should expect from the moderators (should they delete each answer that does not really address the question?). In general, when should an answer be deleted as opposed as just downvoted?

Also, I'm not sure who can see the actual answer, so for the sake of this question, here it is:

> > Some journals implement a double-blind reviewing process, meaning that the reviewers are not aware that the authors are from academia or not
>
> In theory this is true, in practice I think its different.
>
> Most academic fields are quite closed off and small. The possible reviewers and people likely to be published is very small. For example, when I worked in academia we would know who reviewed our papers, and they would know it was us reviewing theirs.

Comment: If it was deleted by a moderator, the moderator should have listed a reason (as a comment on the deleted question).  I can't see the deleted answer, so I don't know what actually happened.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine that answer was deleted because it was an "invalid answer"; it was a comment, and should have been posted as such. Hopefully Anna can stop by and confirm that for herself.

Comment: Yes, I was suspecting something like that, but I was curious about the process for this answer, like if it was flagged before.

Comment: OK, I just noticed that the answer was now actually a comment of my answer, so somehow, it has been moved from answer to comment. I'd still be curious to know what triggered it (i.e. if the poster moved it, and then flag his answer for deletion, or if Anna moved it herself).

Comment: @user102 It was probably flagged by a user for being a comment and not an answer, and subsequently moved by a moderator. This is one of the standard reasons you can choose when flagging.