# Tag for closed questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Following up on our recent discussion [on closed questions](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-should-happen-to-closed-questions), I'm wondering if it might not be a bad idea to create a tag for closed questions. This might help us to "corral" them a bit better.

Thoughts?

Comment: Meta-tags are [to be avoided](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)…

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use `closed:1` in the search query - no need to abuse tags for this.

Comment: See the "[\search](http://academia.stackexchange.com/search)" page for more searching kung-fu.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to "corral" your closed questions.

Closed questions should be destined for one of two fates.

1. Deletion.
2. Reopening.

Time will tell which route a question goes, but having a "pool" of them around is defiantly not the idea you want to promote. As [noted by TheifMaster](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/213/3844) you can already find them for the purposes of doing site cleanup using `closed:1` as part of a search query.

If nobody has expressed any interest in getting the question whipped into shape to re-open (or if it's obvious that isn't going to happen from the get go), they should be deleted. Otherwise they need to be poked until they are ready to open.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good idea, I was actually looking for a way to search only for closed questions.

EDIT: The keyword "closed:1" seems indeed enough, as pointed out by ThiefMaster and Steven Jeuris, so it's probably not necessary to have a tag.

Comment: [You can already search for closed questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125235/157047)